# how to retrieve data from database to table using model view controller(mvc) model in swing

Tags: java, swing

I've written code for view part for table as

```
private JTable table; 
     public String setTableData(Vector data){
        Vector<String> column = new Vector<String>();
        column.addElement("SN");
        column.addElement("Name");
        column.addElement("Last Name");
        column.addElement("Mobile No");
        column.addElement("Email");
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,column);
        table.setModel(model);
        return null;
    }
```

Then I've written model part as follows:

```
   public Vector retriveUser() {
    Connection connection;
    ResultSet resultSet;
    Statement statement = null;
    Vector data = new Vector();
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contact_info", "root", "");
        System.out.println("Connection established");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(retriveUser);
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Vector row = new Vector(columns);
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                row.addElement(resultSet.getObject(i));
            }
            data.addElement(row);
        }
 } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occur");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Then i have written controller

```
 public class ActionBtnListener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String firstName =userView.getfirstName();
        String lastName = userView.getlastName();
        String mobNo = userView.getmobNo();
        String emailAdd = userView.getemailAdd();


        userModel.insertUser(firstName,lastName,mobNo,emailAdd);
        userModel.retriveUser();
        userView.setTableData(null);

    }

 }
```

So,while running i have not seen any table in the form. Only frame was displaying. I want to display database data into view table. And also refresh the table data while submit button is clicked. Please solve my problem.

Comment: StackOverflow is no public coding service.

Comment: If your question is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach based on the duplicate.